# How to check maximum file size using PHP if post_max_size=8000M in php.ini

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp

I configured php.ini in my xampp server with `post_max_size=8000M`, and `upload_max_filesize=2000M`. I want to know how can I validate the maximum upload file size in php. I put this code, and it works. But I don't know if the indicated number (`41943040`) is accurate with the configuration in php.ini

```
if( $_FILES["image"]["size"] >= 41943040 ) {
    echo 'File is too large.';
} else {
    //
}
```

Comment: `8000M = 8GB`, `200M = 200MB` and `41943040 = 40MB`. If you want to allow the same size as the configured max upload size, you don't need to check it manually. PHP will set `$_FILES['image']['error']` to `1` if the file is too large. Basically, check the value of that key and if it's not `0`, then the upload failed. You can see what the different error numbers mean [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I changed my `post_max_size=800M` and `upload_max_filesize=200M`. I think it does not work for me. It shows this `Warning: POST Content-Length of 2147483647 bytes exceeds the limit of 838860800 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: How much data are you posting? How large are your files? `2147483647` (bytes) is 2.14GB while you've set the limit of file uploads to `200MB` and the max post size (files + data) to be `800MB`. If you then try and post 2GB you will obviously get an error since that's _way_ more than the max limits you've set. The limits are just that, limits. You can't send more data than the limit is set to.

Comment: Oh I get it. I changed my `post_max_size=800M` to `post_max_size=8000M`. And now it works. Thank you @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No one else wondering what on earth would you have in an image above 2 gigabytes?